# Can one decode real media file to other media formats using any free C++ library?

Tags: c++

Please provide some pointers on how to convert real media formats to other popular media formats using some C++ sdk(I guess Helix provides one but don't know how to use it).
I am a total newbie in the above area, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec#Implemented_video_codecs) (a library behind ffmpeg and other heavily-used programs) supports some common Real video formats.  See [this page](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html); the tutorial itself is obsolete, but there are linked updates such as [An ffmpeg and SDL Tutorial](http://www.dranger.com/ffmpeg/)

Helix may be an option, but keep in mind the actual Real Video codecs are only available as binaries, while libavcode is fully open source.

Don't expect this to be trivial, whichever library you use.